# Use JavaScript to make a browser download from a file at a given URL

Tags: javascript, browser, download

Assume I have a URL that I want the browser to download without having to visit it. I want to do this using pure JavaScript (no jQuery or other library). There is the method of creating a by doing this:

```
var a  = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute("href", urlToDownloadFrom);
a.setAttribute("download");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

But I don't want to do that because it feels too hackish.

Comment: When you say "download without having to visit it", I immediately think "virus". If that's what you want, go for it, but you'd be much better off just redirecting to the download target and setting appropriate `Content-Disposition` headers.

Comment: What do you mean by "download without having to visit it"?  Does your current solution not work in some way?  What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Why not `window.location.href = '/path/to/file.abc`?